# Compute mean from the object returned by "getSymbols()" in R package "quantmod"

Tags: r, quantmod

I would like to compute moments from the object returned by "getSymbols()" in R package "[quantmod](http://www.quantmod.com)". But the object isn't a vector or matrix, so there is error. How can I do that? Following is my code:

```
> library(quantmod)
> getSymbols("AXP", from = "2007-01-01", to = "2013-12-31")
> returns = diff(AXP[,6]) / lag(AXP[,6]) * 100 # calculate simple return from adjusted prices
> mean(returns)
[1] NA
> var(returns)
                AXP.Adjusted
  AXP.Adjusted           NA
```

How can I calculate its sample mean and variance? Thanks!

Comment: There is no error. You need to supply `na.rm=TRUE` to `mean` and `var` because the first element in the object returned by `diff` is `NA`.

Comment: or just set `returns<- diff(...)[-1] `   :-)  <-- only in this particular case where only the first element is `NA`

Comment: @CarlWitthoft: `lag` also creates a leading `NA`, so that won't quite work. Plus, all the `Ops.xts` methods merge before performing the operation, so that might create `NA` too.

Comment: Perhaps we should be more clear about the error part.  There is no error, because your function completed successfully.  The `NA` (not available) value is returned any time an `NA` is part of any calculation, so while there is no error, there is also no answer to your calculation.  `NA` + 1 = `NA`

Comment: Sorry - I should have been more clear: I meant to imply the full equation,  i.e. `returns <- (everything_on_theleft)[-1]`, but as you say, that only works if you're certain that only the first element of `returns` is `NA` .  Oh, and @Dinre , that's the infamous "code with errors but executes successfully" Inferno Level .

Comment: The R Inferno should be mandatory reading for any serious R user. It's such an excellent free publication.